# Remove floating faces via python

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove floating faces and vertices, it keeps adding them back after I fill holes and triangulate.

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
for vert in bm.verts:
    if len(vert.link_faces) < 1:
        bm.verts.remove(vert)
        print('rm verts: ', vert)
for face in bm.faces:
    for vert in face.verts:
        if len(vert.link_faces)<2:
            bm.faces.remove(face)
            print('rm fac: ', face)
            break  
bm.to_mesh(obj.data)

bmesh.ops.holes_fill(bm, edges=bm.edges)
bmesh.ops.triangulate(bm, faces=bm.faces)
bm.to_mesh(obj.data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bm.faces.remove()` only remove the faces, not the vertices. So `bmesh.ops.holes_fill` refilled those vertices later. To correct it, remove floating faces first. Maybe there's a better way to do this.

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
for face in bm.faces:
    for vert in face.verts:
        if len(vert.link_faces)<2:
            bm.faces.remove(face)
            print('rm fac: ', face)
            break
for vert in bm.verts:
    if len(vert.link_faces) < 1:
        bm.verts.remove(vert)
        print('rm verts: ', vert)

bm.to_mesh(obj.data)

bmesh.ops.holes_fill(bm, edges=bm.edges)
bmesh.ops.triangulate(bm, faces=bm.faces)
bm.to_mesh(obj.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's nearly ALWAYS a good idea to use existing Blender's functions instead of making custom ones from scratch.

Reusing standard functions provides both:  stable work and code elegance.

I've wrote for you the script which deletes all loose (aka "floating") geometry, then fills holes, then triangulates faces.

It's based on standard Blender's functions only.

Here :

---

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.delete_loose(use_verts=True, use_edges=True, use_faces=True)

bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.fill_holes()
bpy.ops.mesh.quads_convert_to_tris(quad_method='BEAUTY', ngon_method='BEAUTY')
```

---

---

[!] By the way, this script works stably on 3.6//4.0//4.1 version-families.